# how to disable '_id' in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, primary-key, pymongo

I just start learning mongodb, and don't know a lot yet.

so my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

import pymongo
import datetime

class AccountsDB():
    def __init__(self):
        self.store_info()

    def store_info(self):
        try:
            conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
            db_name = 'accountsdb'
            coll_name = 'user_info'

            db = conn[db_name]
            coll = db[coll_name]

            print "Successfully connected to '%s'" % db_name

            for i in xrange(20):
                post = {
                    'f_name' : 'Sergey',
                    'l_name' : 'Ivanov',
                    'number' : '777-9-777',
                    'user_id': i
                }
                coll.insert(post)

            print "Done"
        except:
            print "Can't connect to the database"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    acc = AccountsDB()
```

and it gives me :

```
> db.user_info.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c64872bdbff34435192a94"), "l_name" : "Ivanov", "f_name" : "Sergey", "user_id" : 0, "number" : "777-9-777" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c64872bdbff34435192a95"), "l_name" : "Ivanov", "f_name" : "Sergey", "user_id" : 1, "number" : "777-9-777" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c64872bdbff34435192a96"), "l_name" : "Ivanov", "f_name" : "Sergey", "user_id" : 2, "number" : "777-9-777" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c64872bdbff34435192a97"), "l_name" : "Ivanov", "f_name" : "Sergey", "user_id" : 3, "number" : "777-9-777" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c64872bdbff34435192a98"), "l_name" : "Ivanov", "f_name" : "Sergey", "user_id" : 4, "number" : "777-9-777" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50c64872bdbff34435192a99"), "l_name" : "Ivanov", "f_name" : "Sergey", "user_id" : 5, "number" : "777-9-777" }

and so on....
```

But I want to get rid of '_id' and use 'user_id' instead as my primary key. I'm pretty sure it can be done, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the answer is no, you cant disable "_id". why?
just take a look to the [source code of pymongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver). Take a look to [collection.py](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/collection.py) and search for "_id".

Mmm I think this could be done via monkey patching, but its to dark magic. just an idea and I dont recommend monkey patching at all. thats why my answer is no :(

Comment: so I should just use `user_id`, and forget about `_id`?

Comment: When I said no I mean you cant disable "_id", but if you can live with it you can have both "user_id" and "_id". but pymongo uses _id to store objects

Comment: ohh the other way is to fork pymongo implement what you need and send a pull request :). or better first ask for this to the pymongo ppl

Comment: @llazaro You can't. Even if you change pymongo, the _id value will be generated on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
post = {
            'f_name' : 'Sergey',
            'l_name' : 'Ivanov',
            'number' : '777-9-777',
            '_id': i
}
```

With mongoDB, you just use "_id" as the key for the value, and it will use the value you provide instead of auto-generating one.

Or, just create another index on user_id and mark it as "unique"

```
db.collection.createIndex({"user_id":1}, {unique:true})
```

Comment: I think he wants to use 'user_id' instead of '_id'

Comment: @llazaro it can't be done, because the existence of _id is enforced at the server side. However, you are free to create additional unique indexes on any field: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes